# CFA (Level 1) schedule after school and working a 9-5 job

Tags: fixed-income, finance

I am graduating with a BS in math and obviously love math but everything changed when a buddy of mine invited me to an investment society in our school  and I love every single experience. The part I love the most is when when we are researching companies to add to our groups portfolio. So what I am saying is, I found finance a lot more interesting ever since. I took the Canadian Security and I passed it on first try. I started the Investment Management Technique course(failed on my first attempt, but I'll redo it before it expires this year). I had the opportunity of interviewing for a quantitative investment position at a pension, nailed the interview overall but I was not called for a round 2. The experience(interview) was really good and I sent an email to to the interviewee as to how to improve my candidacy and she encouraged me to look into taking the CFA.

I have already bought the schweser study note and I have the CFA curriculum from a year ago. I will register to take it in December because I want to get reimburse by my employer(a back-office firm) when I pass it.

So my question is can anyone tell me how they found time to study given the fact they work so much hours. Also, I want to dedicate 20hrs a week to studying(done university in April), So I would like if people could direct me to website where they make study timetable or even better if you could share your timetable( bear in mind I have no finance background). Also, my plan is to study from schweser directly and use the CFA curriculum to complement and brush over some topics that schweser may not explain into details as well as do the practice questions the whole of November.

Comment: Hi okocj, unfortunately we can't help you with studying. We can help with quantitativily oriented questions in the curriculum. I know special CFA forums exist but I don't use them so I can't point you to them. Good luck with your studies.

Comment: @okocj try www.analystforum.com/forums/CFA-forums/CFA-level-I-forum a ton of information can be found there & also how to study.